# Is there a way to generate separate YouTube embeds for each video in a YouTube Playlist?

Tags: php, jquery, css, youtube, youtube-api

I know how to embed a playlist from YouTube in one player, for example by using the playlist ID in the code below:

`<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="360"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=playlist&list=PL3E6E572E46617B55"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>`

I want a section on my website that pulls each video from a YouTube playlist and makes a *separate* single video YouTube embed for each video, instead of playing each video consecutively in one player. Is this possible? How would I utilize the API to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the YouTube Data API to get each video from the playlist:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list

And the YouTube Player API to create a Video Player for each video that you want to show in your web page:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference